# In Rails, how do I select only a single object type from a relation query?

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, join, relation

How do I select a single entity from a relation?  I’m using Rails 4.2.3.  I have the below query, which joins on another table, but I only wish to delete one of the objects (the object of type “UserMyObjectTimeMatch”) …

```
      user_my_object_time_match = UserMyObjectTimeMatch.joins(:my_object_time)
                                              .select(:user_my_object_time_match)   
                                              .where("race_time_id = ?", linked_my_object.race_times[0].id)
      if !user_my_object_time_match.nil?
        user_my_object_time_match.destroy
      end
```

Unfortunately, when the “user_my_object_time_match.destroy” line is called, a “wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)” error is resulting and I believe it is because the object I’m selecting is not of the right type.  How do  I properly select an object from a relation?

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)? Take a look at the find_by method.

Comment: Yeah but I was reading the section in the documentation about "joins" since I'm using criteria from a relation of the object in question.  I'm not clear how I would combine joins with find_by to get the record of the object type I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `.where` query you will get back an ActiveRecord relation object, which you can loop over, but looking at your query the results that you will get would be

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<UserMyObjectTimeMatch id: nil, user_my_object_time_match: some_id>]
```

even if you loop over this object and do a destroy, the query that is going to run is

```
DELETE FROM "user_my_object_time_matches" WHERE "user_my_object_time_match"."id" = $1  [["id", nil]]
```

id is nil so this is not going to delete anything from your database. You will need to remove that select method, and then do a loop over whatever you get, but since you want a single object try `#find_by(race_time_id: id)` and then in from the result you can directly do a `.destroy`.

If you still want to use `.destroy` using the select query then do a `.select(:id, :user_my_object_time_match))` and then loop over each and destroy.

Answer (score 0):

Using things like `where` will always give you a collection of objects, not just one. (Technically it is not yet an array but a `Relation`, so that you can keep calling more methods like `where`, `select`, `includes`, etc and build up the SQL query before running it.) Also you'll *never* get `nil` from methods like `where`; it will just be a `Relation` that yields zero records (`Foo.where("1=0").to_a` is `[]` not `nil`). So if you "know" you're only going to get zero or one objects, you can do `Foo.where("bar").first`. Then you'll get the object or `nil`.

You may also want to look at `find_by` and `find_by!` which return a single object instead of a relation. You can even use that at the end of other ActiveRecord methods, like `Foo.where("bar").find_by(what: "ever")`.